# Handwritten signature similarity match in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, scikit-image, handwriting-recognition

I am trying to solve problem where i have two digital handwritten signature i have to find similarity percentage between them

Below is the code

```
import cv2
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity as ssim
import numpy as np
# TODO add contour detection for enhanced accuracy

def removeWhiteSpace(img):
    # img = cv2.imread('ws.png') # Read in the image and convert to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = 255*(gray < 128).astype(np.uint8) # To invert the text to white
    coords = cv2.findNonZero(gray) # Find all non-zero points (text)
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(coords) # Find minimum spanning bounding box
    rect = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    return rect
    
def match(path1, path2):
    # read the images
    img1 = cv2.imread(path1)
    img2 = cv2.imread(path2)
    img1 = removeWhiteSpace(img1)
    img2 = removeWhiteSpace(img2)
    # turn images to grayscale
    img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # resize images for comparison
    img1 = cv2.resize(img1, (300, 300))
    img2 = cv2.resize(img2, (300, 300))
    # display both images
    cv2.imshow("One", img1)
    cv2.imshow("Two", img2)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    similarity_value = "{:.2f}".format(ssim(img1, img2,gaussian_weights = True,sigma= 1.2,use_sample_covariance = False)*100)
    # print("answer is ", float(similarity_value),
    #       "type=", type(similarity_value))
    return float(similarity_value)



path1 = 'sample_images\img3.jpeg'
path2 = 'sample_images\img4.jpeg'
similarity_value = match(path1,path2)
print(similarity_value)
```

**Example#1**

Below are the two images

Image1: [image] Image2: [image]

when execute the above code i am getting **77.93** similarity which is good percentage

**Example#2**

Below are the two images

Image1: [image] Image2: [image]

when execute the above code i am getting **66.36** similarity match

**Ask**

How can i improve the similarity match percentage in **example#2** as both images look similar?

Comment: I don't believe that something without neural networks can gives a good result in the wild.

Comment: You probably need to register (align) the two images better and perhaps thicken the lines. See https://learnopencv.com/image-alignment-ecc-in-opencv-c-python/

Comment: A simple idea would be to find contours and try comparing with each other using `cv2.matchShapes` (https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/d45/tutorial_py_contours_more_functions.html#:~:text=OpenCV%20comes%20with%20a%20function,on%20the%20hu%2Dmoment%20values.). It returns a metric where similar shapes have lower score. It is based of Hu moments

Comment: Thanks everyone for your response. I think cv2.matchesShapes is good option as well let me try it

Comment: @AhmedAnsari have you tried cv2.matchesShapes on this?

Comment: Yes @ShubhamTomar but there will be more improvement required so i am working to implement neural network on this

Comment: @AhmedAnsari Can you provide gihub link for Neural Network implementation of your work if possible here.